# Was Rashi a rebellious student?

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, rashi, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

In his commentary to the Talmud, [Rashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi) usually just gives us a simple explanation of the word or phrase he is commenting on. However, every so often he quotes his teachers. It seems to me that when he quotes his teachers he almost always questions their explanation, or outright disagrees.

Is my impression correct that Rashi usually quotes his teachers to disagree with them? Has anyone done a study of all of Rashi's comments to see if there are any such patterns?

If my impression is correct, what could be possible reasons for this tendency?

(Could it be that all his comments are what he received from his teachers and he only mentions them in the few cases where he disagrees?)

Do any Rabbinic sources discuss this?

### A few examples:

**[Shabbat 76b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=76b&format=pdf)**

> אבל רבותי פירשו

**[Shabbat 85b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=85b&format=pdf)**

> כך נראית שיטה זו בעיני ולא פירשו רבותי כן

**[Shabbat 92b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=92b&format=pdf)**

> כך לשון רבותי ולבי מגמגם

**[Shabbat 138b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=138b&format=pdf)**

> כך פירשו רבותי וכן מצאתי בתשובת הגאונים ואיני יודע מהו

**[Rosh Hashanah 25a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=25&format=pdf)**

> כך פירשו רבותי ולבי נוקפי

**[Ketubot 3a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=3&format=pdf)**

> שמעתי כל רבותי מפרשים דקדיש בכספא דקידושי דרבנן נינהו ואי אפשר לומר כן

Comment: By the mere fact that Rash"i didn't learn Chumash or Gemara with Rash"i, we have a problem :-) Seriously - disagreeing with someone's explanation doesn't correlate to being rebellious. Why would you assume that?

Comment: @DanF I used the word "rebellious" liberally to have an attention-grabbing title.

Comment: I assume everything Rashi says is from his teachers. He quotes them explicitly when he disagrees with their interpretation...Although I have seen him quote his teachers even when he agrees with them

Comment: You should read the Ran on Nedarim who very often rejects all the Rishonim and his own rebbes in favour of his own opinion and he should be Blessed for it

Comment: If I remember correctly, in this [podcast on Rashi](https://www.kedma.xyz/2019/04/12.html), he says that the style of learning in the yeshivas Rashi studied in was that the students were taught to argue with their rabbis (and Rashi continued this in his own yeshiva).